# Weird express behaviour to serve js file

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I encounter weird behaviour from Express. I try to serve ejs file based on query. At the same time I have static files configured.
My static files configuration looks like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

My route:

```
 router.get('/blog/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render(`blogPost_${req.params.id}`, {
        path: `blog/${req.params.id}`,
        pageTitle: req.params,
        result: undefined,
    });
});
```

And my ejs blogPost_abc is a typical html file. The problem begins when I add to my ejs file script tag with src:

```
<script src="./test.js"></script>
```

Then in browser when I get /blog/abc express parses it to /blog/test.js and throws an error:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:5000/blog/test.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

And in terminal:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'js'
```

Of course my view engine is set to ejs. Why browser requests .js file even tough I explicitly want 'abc'

Comment: can you try to rename ./test.js into /test.js?

Answer (score 0):

In your views, you need to add [base URL tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

```
<base href="/" target="_blank">
```

> The  HTML element specifies the base URL to use for all relative
> URLs in a document